# how can I get the index of point hovering in Highcharts?

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

[image]

For example, how can I know this is the fifth point of weight_array? Because I have another array named steps_array which is corresponded with weight_array.
I want to add the info of height_array after '55.9'.Such as '55.9 kg 10234 steps'.

code like this.

```js
series:{
  dataLabels:{
     enabled:true,
     formatter:function(){
         return weight_array[$i]+'\t'+height_array[$i];
       }
  }
  
  }
```

Besides, is there any good resource to learn Highcharts? At present, I mainly code based on  example given.But I think it 's short of variability?

Answer (score 1):

I got it.

> this.poinx.index

That's all.